# How do I use goto and make my Log in page the first thing the user sees?

Tags: javascript, backend, svelte, sveltekit, supabase-js

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? My homepage is at src/routes/+page.server and I want users to be redirected there after they log in/sign up. Also, when I run this website, the first thing I see is the home page. Is there a way to not have the homepage be seen before logging in? I am using Supabase for user auth. I was suggested to verify in hooks.server.js that the user is not logged in and redirect to the login/sign-in page. Another idea is to add a popup login window on the home page. If the user isn't logged in, the home page won't work fully and will ask the user to log in. After logging in, a cookie is sent and stored. You can determine if the user is logged in by checking for the presence of a correct cookie – if found, the user is logged in; otherwise, they're not. But, I don't know how to do any of these things work.

```html
// src/routes/+page.svelte - my homepage

<script>
    import {onMount} from 'svelte';
    
    let totalStudyTime = 0;
    let goalHours = 0;
    let goalMinutes = 0;

    let completed = false;

    let minutesInput = 0;
    let hoursInput = 0;

    function calculateCompletion(time, goal) {
        const totalTimeMinutes = time / 60;
        completed = totalTimeMinutes >= goal;
    }

    function setGoal() {
        const totalGoalMinutes = goalHours * 60 + goalMinutes;
        localStorage.setItem('dailyStudyGoal', totalGoalMinutes);
        localStorage.setItem('goalHours', goalHours);
        localStorage.setItem('goalMinutes', goalMinutes);
        totalStudyTime = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('totalStudyTime') || '0', 10) + parseInt(localStorage.getItem('elapsedTime') || '0', 10);
        calculateCompletion(totalStudyTime, totalGoalMinutes);
        
    }

    function formatStudyTime(seconds) {
        const days = Math.floor(seconds / (3600 * 24))
        const hours = Math.floor((seconds % (3600 * 2400)) / 3600);
        const minutes = Math.floor((seconds % 3600) / 60);
        const remainingSeconds = seconds % 60;

        const formattedDays = days > 0 ? `${days} day${days > 1 ? 's' : ''}` : '';
        const formattedHours = hours > 0 ? `${hours} hour${hours > 1 ? 's' : ''}` : '';
        const formattedMinutes = minutes > 0 ? `${minutes} minute${minutes > 1 ? 's' : ''}` : '';
        const formattedSeconds = remainingSeconds > 0 ? `${remainingSeconds} second${remainingSeconds > 1 ? 's' : ''}` : '';

        const timeArray = [formattedDays, formattedHours, formattedMinutes, formattedSeconds].filter(Boolean);
        return timeArray.join(', ');
    }

    onMount (() => {
        goalHours = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('goalHours', goalHours) || '0', 10);
        goalMinutes = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('goalMinutes', goalMinutes) || '0', 10);

        const studyTime = parseInt(localStorage.getItem('totalStudyTime') || '0', 10) + parseInt(localStorage.getItem('elapsedTime') || '0', 10);
        totalStudyTime = studyTime;
        setGoal();
    });

</script>

<main>
<h1><b>Welcome to studyclock!</b></h1>
<h3> Start a study session! </h3>
<p>Set your daily goal! <b> {goalHours} hr {goalMinutes} min </b></p> 

<!-- Input for hours and minutes -->
<label for="hoursInput">Hours</label>
<input type="number" id="hoursInput" bind:value={goalHours} bind:this={hoursInput} min="0">

<label for="minutesInput">Minutes</label>
<input type="number" id="minutesInput" bind:value={goalMinutes} bind:this={minutesInput} min="0" max="59">

<!-- Button to update the daily goal -->
<button on:click={setGoal}>Set Goal</button>

{#if completed}
<p>Great job! You completed your daily study goal! </p>
{/if}

<p> Total study time: <b>{formatStudyTime(totalStudyTime)}</b> </p>
</main>

<style>
    main {
        text-align: center;
    }

    label,
    input,
    button {
        display: block;
        margin: 8px auto;
        text-align: center;
        width: fit-content;
    }

    input {
        margin-bottom: 16px;
    }

    button {
        margin-top: 16px;
    }
</style>

// src/routes/login/+page.svelte


<script>
    import supabase from "../../routes/supa";
    import { goto } from "$app/navigation";

    let email = "";
    let password = "";

    async function handleLogin(email, password) {
        const {user, error} = await supabase.auth.signIn({
            email: email,
            password: password
        }); 
        if (user) {
            goto("/");
        } else {
    console.error(error);
}
}

function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    handleLogin(email, password);
}

</script>


<div class="loginFormContainer">
    <h1>Login</h1>
    <form class="loginForm" on:submit={handleSubmit}>
        <input type="email" bind:value={email} placeholder="email@email.com"/>
        <input type="password" bind:value={password} placeholder="Password"/>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
    <a href="/signup">Not a member? Sign up!</a>
</div>

<style>

.loginFormContainer {
    padding: 30px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    box-shadow: 2px 4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    background-color: var(--bg-2);
    max-height: 80vh;
    max-width: 100vh;
    }
</style>


// src/routes/signup/+page.svelte

<script>
    import supabase from "../../routes/supa";
    import { goto } from "$app/navigation";

    let email = "";
    let password = "";

    async function handleSignup(email, password) {
        const {user, error} = await supabase.auth.signUp({
            email: email,
            password: password
        }); 
        if (user) {
            goto("/");
        } else {
    console.error(error);
}
}

function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    handleSignup(email, password);
}
</script>
<div class="signupFormContainer">
```

Comment: in any page that requires a user to be logged in, check if the user is logged in, if not, "goto" login page (sorry, I don't know svelte enough to write actual code, but that's the general idea)

Comment: Here is a radical idea: Make the homepage the login-page. And if the user goes to the "home page" while they are logged in, redirect them to the app.

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest you the solution, but not actually will be referencing to a Supabase setup.

You can check if the user is logged in on your home page load function, if not redirect it to the login page.

```
// src/routes/+page.server.ts

import type { PageServerLoad } from './$types'
import { redirect } from '@sveltejs/kit';

export const load: PageServerLoad = async ({ cookies }) => {
    // getUser is some method that determines if the user is logged or not based on a cookie, usually checking a session on DB.
    const user = await getUser(cookies);

    if (!user) {
        // User not logged in.
        throw redirect(302, '/login');
    }

    return {
        // Return your home page data here.
    }
}
```

And in your login page a similar, but contrary, approach, if the user is already logged redirect it to the home page.

```
// src/routes/login/+page.server.ts

import type { PageServerLoad } from './$types'
import { redirect } from '@sveltejs/kit';

export const load: PageServerLoad = async ({ cookies }) => {
    // getUser is some method that determines if the user is logged or not based on a cookie, usually checking a session on DB.
    const user = await getUser(cookies);

    if (user) {
        // User already logged.
        throw redirect(302, '/');
    }

    return {
        // Return your login page data here if needed.
    }
}
```

My actual suggestion to solve your problem is that you should leverage the load patterns offered by SvelteKit by using the load functions.

SvelteKit offers an example similar to what I propose you by [using redirects](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#redirects). You should check the documentation for [data loading](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load) in general.